# Permission on Ubuntu with Apache and external software

Tags: php, apache, shell

something is wrong in the permissions and I've tried everything to fix it. I've already given permission on every way and file I know of. I even created a group and added users but it didn't work. I used Ubuntu 22.04, apache server, php 8.1. Reminder that the code works fine in terminal with sudo or with normal user.

I already added www-data with full permissions but that didn't work either. Something is missing for me.

Block of code to try access external program

```
public function run(){
       $cmd_program = sprintf('%s %s %s%s', self::ANALYSIS_APP,  self::OUTPUT_FILE,         self::INPUT_FILE,$_SESSION['fileName']. " 2>&1");
          echo exec($cmd_program,$out_program);
    }
```

output:

`sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/program: Permission denied`

my directory /var/www/ has group permission and the group has 3 users: the pc user, www-data and nobody

My sudoers file in http session:

`www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

EDIT2

The /usr/local/bin/program have permission 755 and is a link symbolic to a folder on downloads.

EDIT 3

The resolution I got was add sudo -S
`sudo -S /usr/local/bin/program`

But I wanted to control the permissions so I wouldn't be adding sudo every time there was a problem.

Any help?